# Can we achieve website monitoring from different geographical locations using nagios or Nagios plugin i.e. gearman?

Tags: web, nagios, gearman, nagiosxi

I'm in the project to implement website monitoring from difference geographical locations using `nagios`.

Can anyone help me to understand this better that how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No first-hand experience with Nagios, but we did develop a website monitoring service (as a trial project) using [Uptime](https://github.com/fzaninotto/uptime) - an open source project based on Node.js, MongoDB and Bootstrap and after the initial setup, config etc. was done, it worked quite well right out of the box. It might be worth a look/try.

https://github.com/fzaninotto/uptime